# RadAjaxManager AjaxRequest TypeError: Cannot read property 'id' of undefined

Tags: javascript, telerik, radajaxmanager

Here's the situation:
I have a host page that loads a custom web user control.  In my web control I want use javascript and a RadAjaxManager to load up a second web user control.  I used this example from Telerik as my guide:
http://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-ajax/ajax/examples/manager/clientsideapi/defaultvb.aspx

However, I kept getting the following error when I would call the client-side "ajaxRequest" method on the RadAjaxManager.

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'id' of undefined
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I finally figured it out!
On my parent web control I already had implemented a RadAjaxManager.  So when I loaded up my second web control with its own RadAjaxManager, the javascript was getting confused as to which manager to use.

Enter: RadAjaxManagerProxy -> http://www.telerik.com/help/aspnet-ajax/ajax-ajaxmanagerproxy.html

After implementing this, my controls worked beautifully!

Hope this helps others, if not myself later down the road when I forget.

Comment: Did you really answer your question at the exact same time you asked it?

Comment: @FrancisP No, I actually worked on it until I figured it out.  I then posted it out here and answered it myself; exercising the "Answer your own question" option.  http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/07/its-ok-to-ask-and-answer-your-own-questions/

Answer (score 10):

Another reason this error can happen is not having clientIDMode="AutoID" attribute in the `<pages>` element of your web.config

Comment: ..or if you have anything else than clientIDMode="AutoID" on your ajaxified server control.

Comment: And make sure that the MS AJAX extensions are installed on the production server.